Finding the smallest possible value $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ for $g(x)=e^{1-x^2}-2\sqrt{\sin\frac{\pi}{2x}}$ to be continuous on $[\alpha,\infty)$
I've been given this question about continuity for my real analysis subject and I have been struggling to approach this question: find the smallest value of $\alpha  \in\mathbb R$ such that the function $g: [\alpha , \infty) \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$g(x)=e^{1-x^2}-2\sqrt{\sin\frac{\pi}{2x}}$ is continuous. Any advice would be appreciated thanks.

The first term $e^{1-x^2}$ is continuous everywhere because it is a composition of an exponential and a polynomial, so the continuity of $g$ is only affected by where $2\sqrt{\sin\frac{\pi}{2x}}$ is continuous. We need $2\sqrt{\sin\frac{\pi}{2x}}$ to be defined for it to be continuous; because of the $\sqrt{\cdots}$, we need $\sin\frac{\pi}{2x}$ to be non-negative. Does this help?

As @Alan Rosas suggested , $$e^{1-x^2}$$ is continuous everywhere so the continuity of $g(x)$ depends entirely on the second term.
Let $$f(x)=\sqrt{\sin{\frac \pi{2x}}}$$
On thing to be noted is that,
if $f(x)$ is defined in $(a,b)$, then $f(x)$ is also continuous in $(a,b)$.
This reduces our problem to find the smallest $\alpha$ such that $f(x)$ is defined in $[\alpha,\infty)$
for $f(x)$ to be defined $\sin{\frac \pi{2x}}$ must be positive in $[\alpha,\infty)$
as $x$ increases $\frac \pi{2x}$ decreases and approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$, at $x=0\;\frac \pi{2x} \to\infty$, so $\sin{\frac \pi{2x}}$ is undefined for $x=0$.
We know that the smallest values of $x$ for which $\sin x$ is positive are $x\in[0,\pi]$
So we need to find the interval of $x$ for which $\frac \pi{2x} \in[0,\pi]$ which gives us $x\in\left[\frac 12,\infty\right)$
so the smallest value of $\alpha$ for which $g(x)$ is continuous is $\alpha=\frac 12$
This can also be verified by plotting the graph of $g(x)$. Refer here
